# Is a stronger version of the Erdős-Turan conjecture on arithmetic progessions reasonable? (And related questions.)

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, arithmetic-progression

Define the size, possibly $\infty$, of a set $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ as $|S|=\sum\limits_{n\in S} \frac{1}{n}$. Then the [Erdős-Turan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions) conjecture states that if $|S|=\infty$, S must contain arbitrarily long APs (arithmetic progressions).

**Q1**: has anyone conjectured that for each $k>0$ there must be a finite constant $c_k$ such that: $S$ is $k$-free $\implies |S|\le c_k$? ($k$-free meaning that $S$ is free from APs of length $k$.) Related: **Q6** below.

**Q2**: if so are there explicit (and somewhat tight) formulas for $c_k$? A plausible one to me would appear $c_k=k\log(k)$.

**Q3**: currently, are the largest known $k$-free sets the greedy ones? I'd be very curious to see a counterexample here!
Some greedy sets are in OEIS:

k=3: [A003278](http://oeis.org/A003278), size $\approx 3.007938999898936$

k=4: [A005837](http://oeis.org/A005837), size $\approx 4.285$

k=5: [A020655](http://oeis.org/A020655), size $\approx 7.8723048$

k=7: [A020658](http://oeis.org/A020658), size $\approx 13.497609$

**Q4 & Q5**: if $k$ is prime, the greedy $k$-free set mentioned above is very easily proved to be $1+\{n\in \mathbb{N}_0 \mid \text{the base-} k \text{ expansion of } n \text{ does not contain the digit } k-1\}$. Is there any description of the sets, even partial, when $k$ is not prime? (In particular for $k=4$, which already seems to be quite impenetrable.)
Is there a formula for the sizes, in terms of well known constants and functions, at least when $k$ is prime? Euristically I observed that for prime $k$, the sizes approach $k\log(k)$ (from below?) as $k \rightarrow\infty$.

**Q6**: the OEIS page for $k=3$ ([A003278](http://oeis.org/A003278)) links to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1557) claiming to settle **Q1** for $k=3$. I couldn't follow it, but I notice that the result is not mentioned in the Wikipedia article, nor in this [slightly later paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5800) by Thomas F. Bloom...
So is the former paper not correct, or even not to be taken seriously? (By the way, a first edition of Newman's *Analytic number theory*, referred to therein, is freely available on the [Internet Archive Library](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-0-387-22740-5).)

Comment: I think that in your **Q1**, you mean for the implication to go the other way. Otherwise it's too easy: of course for any $k$, there are sets of arbitrarily small "size" containing length-$k$ progressions: for example, there are lots of length-$4$ progressions in the set $[10^6,10^6+3] \cup [10^{12},10^{12}+3] \cup \dots$.

Comment: Tim Gowers's answer here seems relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13230/erdos-conjecture-on-arithmetic-progressions/25404#25404

Comment: @WillBrian: you are absolutely right!

Comment: @WillBrian: thank you for the pointer to Gower's sensible point. Even though it doesn't answer my question it does manage to reduce the "gap" between problem and solution in a way, by making my question definitely less interesting.

Comment: ... Gowers's...