# Density and sums of reciprocals

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a notion of density for a (strictly increasing) sequence of natural numbers that decides whether the sum of the reciprocals of that sequence converges?

Comment: Well, the function $A \mapsto \sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n}$ is a countably additive measure on $\mathbb{N}$, though I assume this isn't quite the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: The nicest characterization I know is the Muntz-Satz theorem (it is strange to say theorem-theorem, but that is what people call it).  See
http://wapedia.mobi/en/Müntz–Szász_theorem

Comment: Since the link in the above comment is not working, here is a Wikipedia link: [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem).

Answer (score 6):

The notion of natural density gives a suficient condition. Namely, one can prove that if $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ has positive upper natural density then $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}$ diverges. This condition is not a necessary one, though. A well-known result in number theory ascertains that the series of the reciprocals of the prime numbers diverges whereas $\pi(n) = o(n)$.

In the following list you are to encounter some previous discussions on MO that are closely related to the current inquiry of yours:

[**1**] [Erdos Conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13230/erdos-conjecture-on-arithmetic-progressions)

[**2**] [On the series 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/11 + ...](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4596/on-the-series-1-2-1-3-1-5-1-7-1-11)

**References**

**I**. *Erdös's brilliant proof of the divergence of* $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p}$:
http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1938-13.pdf

**II**. [A. Rice](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3632/alex-rice), [*Density and substance: an investigation into the size of integer subsets.*](http://alexricemath.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/DensityAndSubstance.pdf)