# Two notions of thinness of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, measure-theory

If $A$ is a subset of the set of positive integers $\mathbb{N}$, there are (at least) two notions of what it means for $A$ to be *thin*:

1. $A$ is thin in the 1st sense if $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} = 0$; and
2. $A$ is thin in the 2nd sense if $\sum_{a\in A}\frac {1}{a} < \infty$.

As user Dieter Kadelka points out in the comments below, (1) does not imply (2). Does (2) imply (1)?

**EDIT.** Originally there was a 3rd notion of thinness ("$A$ is thin in the 3rd sense if $\prod_{a\in A}\frac{a}{a+1} > 0$"), but David Loeffler pointed out that this is equivalent to notion 2 above (see comments).

Comment: (2) is surely equivalent to (3), because $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, so the difference between partial sums and partial products is bounded above.

Comment: Oh thanks @DavidLoeffler - I guess I will remove (3) and adapt the title.

Comment: If $A$ is the set of primes then 1. holds true but 2. is false.

Comment: It’s a simple exercise to show that 2 implies 1.

Comment: This link has a few of the well known notions of density, including both the ones in the question, as well as how they interrelate: https://oeis.org/wiki/Density

Comment: [mathoverflow.se]: [Density and sums of reciprocals](https://mathoverflow.net/q/32988) [math.se]: [If $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ and $\sum\limits_{a\in A}\frac1a$ converges then $A$ has natural density $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5932),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $|A \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}| / n \leq \sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}$ 2. implies 1. But if $A$ is the set of primes 1. holds true and 2. is false.