# Numerical and topological density

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers, and let's say that $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is *numerically dense* if $$\text{lim inf}_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} = 1.$$
Is there a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that the collection of numerically dense subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ equals the collection of topologically dense subsets of $(\mathbb{N},\tau)$?

Comment: Do you need inf?

Comment: Just a comment: Furstenberg topology does not work, and finite non-empty subsets cannot be open. Where does this question come from?

Comment: @Paolo I was goofing around with dense sets (in the sense of *numerically dense* above) and wondered whether they could be dense with respect not only to this "lim (inf)" measure, but with respect to a topology.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti We can say more - nonempty set $A$ with asymptotic density zero can't be open, because then $\mathbb N\setminus A$ would be numerically and hence topologically dense, yet it wouldn't intersect $A$.

Comment: @Wojowu yes, we can also add that if $X$ has upper asymptotic density $x>0$ then its interior $\mathrm{Int}(X)$ has upper asymptotic density $x$ too (and $X/\mathrm{Int}(X)$ has density $0$); also, if $X,Y$ are open sets then $X \cap Y$ is empty or has positive upper asymptotic density..

Comment: Maybe the question would actually be simpler if we generalized it: can we give a simple necessary and sufficient condition on a set of subsets of $X$ to be the sense sets of some topology on $X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have such a topology on $\mathbb{N}$. Let $\{A_\alpha : \alpha < \mathfrak{c}\}$ be an uncountable almost disjoint family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. For each $\alpha$, let
$$B_\alpha = \bigcup\{[2^n,2^{n+1}) : n \in A_\alpha\}.$$
Notice that $\{B_\alpha : \alpha < \mathfrak{c}\}$ is still an almost disjoint family, but it has the additional property that each $B_\alpha$ meets every dense set of our alleged topology. In other words, each $B_\alpha$ has nonempty interior. These interiors must be disjoint, since if $\alpha \neq \beta$ then the complement of $B_\alpha \cap B_\beta$ is dense. Thus, taking interiors, we get an uncountable family of disjoint nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{N}$,  such that

$$\{S \in 2^{\mathbb{N}} \colon S \,\, \mbox{is numerically dense}\} \subsetneq \{D \in 2^{\mathbb{N}} \colon D \,\, \mbox{is a dense subset of} \,\,(\mathbb{N},\tau)\}.$$

[We say that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4596/on-the-series-1-2-1-3-1-5-1-7-1-11) a subset $c$ of $\mathbb{N}$ is *closed* if either the sum of the reciprocals of the elements of $C$ converges or $C = \mathbb{N}$. It can be shown that the family $\{\mathbb{N} \setminus C \colon C \,\, \mbox{is closed}\}$ determines a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$. It can also be proven that $D \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a dense subset of $(\mathbb{N},\tau)$ if and only if the series of the reciprocals of the elements of $D$ diverges: since the series of the reciprocals of any numerically dense subset of $\mathbb{N}$ diverges, it follows that any such set belongs to $$\{D \in 2^{\mathbb{N}} \colon D \,\, \mbox{is a dense subset of} \,\,(\mathbb{N},\tau)\}$$ and the purported inclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought that the following provides a negative answer, and posted this for comments. Will Brian points out below that the last claim is wrong.
It may still be useful as a starting point, so I do not delete this answer.
In the notation below, one seems to need a family $\mathcal{A}$ that is closed under finite intersections and such that $\mathcal{A}\setminus\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ and every element of $\mathcal{N}$ contains an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

A *semifilter* is a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that for each set $A\in\mathcal{F}$, all supersets of $A$ are in $\mathcal{F}$. 
For a semifilter $\mathcal{F}$, define
$$
\mathcal{F}^+:=\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N} : A^c\notin \mathcal{F}\}.
$$
Then 
$\mathcal{F}^+$ is also the family of all sets that intersect all members of
the semifilter $\mathcal{F}$. We also have that $\mathcal{F}^{++}=\mathcal{F}$.

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the (semi)filter of all density 1 sets,
and $\mathcal{N}$ be the family of neighborhoods, i.e., sets containing open sets, in the expected topology.
You request that $\mathcal{N}^+=\mathcal{D}$ or, equivalently, that 
$$
\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{D}^+=\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N} : A^c\notin \mathcal{D}\},
$$
the family of all sets of positive upper density.
(And here comes the gap...) But then there are two elements of $\mathcal{N}$ whose intersection is nonempty but has zero density; a contradiction.

Comment: @SalvoTringali Can you give an example of two members of $F$ such that their intersection is not in $F$? Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644932/intersection-of-dense-sets-in-mathbbn

Comment: @Dominic. I jumped to hasty conclusions. I take my comment back, and agree that $F$ is a filter. On the other hand, what's the meaning of the superscript '+' appended to a subfamily of $\mathcal P(\mathbf N)$?

Comment: @Boaz: I follow your argument up until the last line. If $\mathcal N$ is defined as the family of sets containing open sets (but they need not be open), then I see no contradiction in having two elements of $\mathcal N$ with nonempty, zero-density intersection.

Comment: @WillBrian: Thanks. I've updated the "answer" accordingly.